# jQuery UI Menu Won't Render Second tier

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm just using jQueryUI for my first time and I'm having some trouble with it.  I'm trying to get a two tiered menu but the second tier isn't rendering.. Instead, items that should be placed in the second tier are added to the first one.

Here is my markup:

```
<div id='maps'>
    <h2>Maps</h2>
    <ul id='maps-list'>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Content is added using the following javascript function:

```
function maps_reload() {

    map_list().done( function( data ) {

        var list = '';
        for( i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            list += '<li><a href="javascript:map_display_info( ' + data[i].id + ')">' + data[i].name + '</a>';
            list += '<ul>';
            list += '<li><a href="javascript:update_map( ' + data[i].id + ' )">Update Map</a></li>';
            list += '<li><a href="javascript:display_map( ' + data[i].id + ' )">Display Map</a></li>';
            list += '<li><a href="javascript:delete_map( ' + data[i].id + ' )">Delete Map</a></li>';
            list += '</ul></li>';
        }
        list += '<li>&nbsp;</li>';
        list += '<li><a href="javascript:show_add_map()">Add a new map</a></li>';
        $( '#maps-list' ).html( list );
    });

    $( '#maps-list' ).menu();
}
```

The resulting structure is

```
<ul id='maps-list'>
    <li>
         <a>Map</a>
         <ul>
               <li><a>Update Map</a></li>
               <li><a>Display Map</a></li>
               <li><a>Delete Map</a></li>
         </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Which meets the requirements... I think?

Can anyone see any issues in my code?

Cheers

Comment: what do you want the layout to look like

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/menu/ Notice how Delphi and Salzburg have a second tier of menu?  Thhat's what I would like to happen

Comment: why aren't the anchors showing in your HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add anchors to your links like  for each menu item for this to work (except I noticed you have links for each menu item hmm.)

example:  http://jsfiddle.net/7dw9h/

http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/

```
<ul id='maps-list'>
    <li>
         <a href="#" >Map</a>
         <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Update Map</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Display Map</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Delete Map</a></li>
         </ul>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in your code this code is working,if you want to test it then you need to call function `$( '#maps-list' ).menu();` outside the the function `maps_reload()`.

Test the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4LUDz/1/